# How to compare an item to the next item in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I currently have a table

```
            INDEX Open     
2018-12-31   0    104.000  
2019-01-02   1    105.000  
2019-01-03   2    111.000  
2019-01-04   3    110.000
```

How can I compare the first item to the next item in the open column for each item? I currently have a loop with a counter and I just use the counter -1 to compare it to the previous item as long as (counter -1) is greater than 0 so I don't get an index out of range error. I want to compare the items and then work out the difference in % for each of them to the next day and then add the results as a new column in the database

Result should be

```
            INDEX     Open     %Change
2018-12-31 .....    0 .... 104.000 ....   Nothing because 1st item nothing to compare too 
2019-01-02 .....    1 .... 105.000 ....   .96 
2019-01-03 .....    2 .... 111.000 ....   5.71
2019-01-04 .....    3 .... 110.000 ....   -0.9
```

So I want to compare index 1 to index 0 and work out the % change so 105/104 - 1 * 100 and the same all the way through the table. I am sure theres a way to do this I just haven't figured it out, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function in pandas for doing just that:

```
df.Open.pct_change()
#2018-12-31         NaN
#2019-01-02    0.009615
#2019-01-03    0.057143
#2019-01-04   -0.009009
```